# How can I turn on/off WiFi programatically on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, wifi

I would like to know if there is any possibility to turn wifi on and off programatically. My idea is to have a background task looking for geocoordinates and toggle the wifi settings wether the phone is in the range of a former saved location or not.

Yet everything I saw were apps which get the state of the wifi and quick jump to the wifi settings. I would like to implement a more automated app which helps saving battery power.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, you can't programmatically turn on or off the wifi. The best you can do is displaying the WIFI settings page and let the user take care of it.

Answer (score 5):

You can show the dialog like this.

```
ConnectionSettingsTask connectionSettingsTask = new ConnectionSettingsTask();
connectionSettingsTask.ConnectionSettingsType = ConnectionSettingsType.WiFi; 
connectionSettingsTask.Show();
```